# Set bind with Alt key - Java

Tags: java, bind, key-bindings, alt, virtual-keyboard

I have two key binds on my code:

```
private void enterBind(){

    String key = "ENTER";
    KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key);

    //code  
}

private void altSBind(){

    String key = "VK_S";
    KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key);

    //code
}
```

The enter bind is fully working, but the "Alt S" bind is not, I tryed to research what should I insert in the place of "VK_S" but until I got no sucess on it. Is this simple to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"alt shift X" => getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, InputEvent.ALT_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK);
"alt shift released X" => getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, InputEvent.ALT_MASK | InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK, true);
```

This might help.

Comment: Just to clearfy, I was wanting just to hit Alt+S and the code up is for Alt+Shift+S, which means if you remove the InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK it will work the way I want. +1 for the awesome answer, ty